# Is it possible for a NIC to send data when only the eth TX+ and TX- (eth) lines are connected?

Tags: nic, ethtool

I have a high security network that needs to send data to a less secure network.

The connection must be physically unable to send data from the low security network to the high security network.

I would like to achieve this via a modified ethernet cable. The cable has only one TX+ to RX+ (pin 1 to 3)  and one TX- to RX- (pin 2 to 6) connected.  Both sending and receiving PCs are running ubuntu.

So far I have tested setting the cards to Full-Duplex Speed 100 and added an entry in the arp table of the sender for the receiver's mac address.

Accordingly, it fails. TCPdump shows no packets leaving the sending machine.

Is there anything else I can do or is there a mistake in the set-up?

Comment: That's usually done with a firewall.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: for this application I need to guarantee no possible return communication. A data diode is one possible option but  I was hoping to find a cheaper alternative.

Comment: You need to loop tx back to rx on the sending side. Otherwise you won't get link and the card won't transmit. I can write a more complete answer later today.

Comment: `A unidirectional network (also referred to as a unidirectional gateway or data diode) is a network appliance or device that allows data to travel in only one direction.` - so, a firewall.

Comment: `The connection must be physically unable to send data from the low security network to the high security network.` It's called a portable mass storage device.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Commonly in operational technology systems it's desirable to get monitoring data from the device to external systems, without any chance of data going in other direction - as the systems may literally kill people. I work with securing such systems, and this question is perfectly legitimate. Suggesting a firewall is not enough in such situations. It may be regulatory requirements.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Apricorn-Validated-256-bit-Encryption-ASK3-120GB/dp/B00W2EN8CE/ref=sxin_27_pa_sp_phone_search_thematic_sspa Apricorn 120GB Aegis Secure Key FIPS 140-2 Level 3 Validated 256-bit Encryption USB 3.0 Flash Drive

Comment: @GregAskew Excellent solution *to a different problem*. Real time monitoring requires something better than USB drives.

Comment: nope, on a business environment you want to send and receive or deny access. but not trying to get a hacking device

Comment: @djdomi The point is to make a one way flow of traffic. This is very common in control systems. Google *data diode*. It's often useful to have data flowing from control systems into ERP systems, thus the need.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, I should be more paranoid and use my aluminum helmet often to think about the abilities they gain ;) I will forward it as a idea to ulour security DEP ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, both devices needs to have RX connected.

[image: Sender]

Sender is on left, receiver is on right. This way, both sides will see link. Note that this is out of spec, as you have more load than normal, so it's recommended to use short cables and good quality NIC's, and a point to point connection rather than to a switch.

For a NIC to sense link on a 100Mb Full Duplex link, it doesn't need the TX pairs connected, only RX pairs. Furthermore, it will happily accept itself as partner. Thus, both partners will have link.

This can even be exploited into making a passive Ethernet tap, by simply connecting the TX pair to RX on a card to sniff traffic without chance of sending traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. TCP is a bidirectional protocol, the sender sends SYN to wake up the receiver and expects ACK-SYN back to say the receiver is awake before it will send anything. Hardware may sense no carrier on the cut lines and not bother to send the initial SYN.

As Gerald Schneider pointed out in a comment, the simplest way to make this work is with a hardware firewall.

Comment: Is this still the case if UDP is used? My understanding was that UDP does not  require bidirectional communication.

Comment: Has to be a guess, but given that you're seeing no packets outbound, I'd have to say that your hardware, not having an RX line, is not seeing carrier from the other card, assuming no cable connection, and so is not sending anything. You're correct, though, that if you could fake a carrier, likely UDP would transit OK.

Comment: That was my conclusion as well. The other test would be to use a switch and try to broadcast it. With the modified cable connected from the switch to the receiving NIC.

Comment: You'd still run into the same problem. The switch, not seeing carrier from the chopped cable, would not send data out the port. Even a hub would likely not send data to an effectively empty socket.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: regardless of the Protocol, as an electrian and it professionals, it also exist [Ethernet single paired for upto 10mbit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair#Single-pair) in case you really want to solve a pairing issue or be legit on also want to sent traffic

Comment: @djdomi Thanks. In my application I need communication in one direction only.  100BaseT ( as apposed to 100BaseTX )   would provide communication in both directions.